# GitLab-CI for grails project

Tags: grails, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I move to GitLab and use all his tools that comes with it.
I installed GitLab v8.0.4, on my CentOs7 with Tomcat. I create a project and push a grails example to the git project.
Now I'd like to be able, every time I push a file to the project, to fire up a deploy. In jenkis I was able to pull the project, compile it with grails cmd tool, and deploy the war to the Tomcat.
I'm trying to do the same but I really feel lost. Does anybody have never try this, and can show me how to do?

Answer (score 1):

If the deployment script is in the same repository as the project itself, you can have a build stage and a deploy stage. If the the build stage succeeds, it will start the deployment stage. The .gitlab-ci.yml could look like this:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build_grails:
  stage: build
  script:
  - build-script_of_grails_cmd

deploy_to_tomcat:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - deploy_script_with_capistrano_or_whatever
```

If your deployment code is in another project you can trigger this project to start the deployment when the build stage has finished. The deployment repo should have a trigger setup. This can be done in the continuous integration menu of the deployment project. After setting up a trigger, GitLab generates a triggering curl snippet you can paste in the yml-file. The grails app gitlab-ci.yml will look like this:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build_grails:
  stage: build
  script:
  - build-script_of_grails_cmd

trigger:
  type: deploy
  script:
    - curl -X POST -F token=4579a6f10c51f0a4b7bdbd384f6e53 https://gitlab-comewhere.com/ci/api/v1/projects/5/refs/master/trigger
```

The gitlab-ci.yml in the deployment project will look like this:

```
stages:
  - deploy

deploy_to_tomcat:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - deploy_script_with_capistrano_or_whatever
```